# What is the role of the そうに?

Tags: grammar, translation

The whole sentence is:

> 子どもたちは小さな雪だるまを作って、楽し**そうに**遊んでいました。

What is the role of そうに in this sentence?

Comment: What do you make of the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

楽しい is an い-adjective meaning "fun".  In Japanese, there's nothing wrong with saying "I'm having fun."  But generally you're not going to presume to know the psychological state of someone else.

楽しそう is formed by dropping い and adding そう, forming a な-type adjective meaning, "appearing to be having fun".

So the sentence

> 子どもたちは小さな雪だるまを作って、楽しそうに遊んでいました。

could be translated as "The children were having fun playing and making small snowmen."  Though with such a short snippet of a sentence, the feeling I get is that you could just render it simply as "The kids were having fun making snowmen."